# Angular2 RC1 angular2-infinite-scroll 403 (Forbidden) Error

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I am trying to add angular2-infinite-scroll plugin in to my project.

I am able to installed and add it without any issue.

I have also updated my systemjs.config.js and added below code:

```
var map = {
        'app': 'content/app',
        'rxjs': 'node_modules/rxjs',
        'angular2-infinite-scroll': 'node_modules/angular2-infinite-scroll',
        '@angular': 'node_modules/@angular'
    };
```

But when I run it in my browser I receive below error:

```
/node_modules/angular2-infinite-scroll/ 403 (Forbidden)
```

Can anyone please guide?